# after replacing icv,intake boot,valve cover gasket and return to stock air box from CAI,car will not hold idle 325i 1994

Tags: car, idle, air-intake

Car will not idle after re-installing stock air box from previous cold air intake. I replaced idle control valve also replaced intake boot as well as valve cover gasket along with spark plugs, BMW 325i 1994.added information, the car starts up but in order for it to keep running the accelerator has to be pushed over and over,the maf sensor was replaced and installed in correct direction,I also tried searching for vacuum leaks but there was no change in rpm,could the hoses to the intake boot be in wrong position?

Comment: Welcome to the site! We could use more details on the idle condition please. Does it idle at high RPM, is it a rough idle or do the RPMs jump all over, does the engine die immediately or after some time, does it change with engine temp? My initial thought is a vacuum leak, can you hear any hissing when it's trying to idle? Did you reinstall the MAF sensor in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the CAI, or did you buy it from someone else? If it was someone else, they may have installed a chip or had the ECU re-flashed to take advantage of the increased airflow. If so, then you'll need to re-flash the ECU with a stock tune.

Did you gap the plugs properly before you installed them? That's an easy step to forget, especially when you're replacing several things at the same time. And have friends helping you. Friends with beer.